When script is in headless mode facing error: ERR_ABORTED; maybe frame was detached
[2024-04-12 13:22:30,522: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Facing Error: ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n',  '  File "/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_frame.py", line 210, in continuation\n    raise Error(event["error"])\n', 'playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_ABORTED; maybe frame was detached?\n']
how to handle if there is a change in page/window render
Any new page or rendering on that page

Please share a [mcve] of the code that causes the error. There's no way to help otherwise.
